# scraping multiple pages from geeksforgeeks.org using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

[image]

I want to scrape multiple pages of search results from [geeksforgeeks.org](https://geeksforgeeks.org) using Selenium. The challenge lies in how to scrape the number of pages and how to navigate to the next page by clicking the 'Next' button.

```
next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='ant-pagination-item-link']")
next_button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you have there several problems.

1. `next_button` has incorrect locator, it should be `[class*=ant-pagination-next]`
2. When you scroll to target element, native methods doesn't wait for scroll, so your click is not performed on correct location
3. Even if you wait for scroll, target place is overlapped by nav bar

So, you should scroll to element with offset (I was lazy to get element dimensions, just defined `-100`), wait for element location to be stable and only then click on element. Also, be aware, that login modal can appear after first click.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium import webdriver

def wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(element):
    initial_location = element.location
    previous_location = initial_location
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < 1:
        current_location = element.location
        if current_location != previous_location:
            previous_location = current_location
            start_time = time.time()
        time.sleep(0.4)

actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
url = "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/"
driver.get(url)

next_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class*=ant-pagination-next]')))
actionChains.scroll_by_amount(next_button.location['x'], next_button.location['y'] - 100).perform()
wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(next_button)
next_button.click()
```

to get pages amount you can use

```py
pages_amount = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class,'ant-pagination-jump-next')]//following-sibling::*[contains(@class, 'item ant-pagination-item-')]").text
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have encountered this error: 'AttributeError: 'ActionChains' object has no attribute 'scroll_by_amount

Comment: @MarwaMriwa add import. :) `from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains`
`

Comment: If it is not clear, I added imports to code snippet. :)

Comment: the problem is ActionChains object has no attribute scroll_by_amount

Comment: https://monosnap.com/file/VtrJ51qDA8ujaTYvnbkbKzUDYNJD7E
It should. What version of Selenium are you use?

Comment: Just copy my code snippet again with provided imports

Comment: version of Selenium is 4.1.3

Comment: if it really doesn't work, that's similar solution (replace actionChains line):

`scrollY = next_button.location["y"] - 100
script = f"window.scrollTo(0, {scrollY});"
driver.execute_script(script)`

Answer (score 0):

Use this locator instead, as the one you provided resolves to more than one element.

```
next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@aria-label="right"]')
next_button.click()
```

For the number of pages, you just need to get the text value of locator that carries that value